# How do delete XELEMENT in XDocument?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, xelement

```
  <Settings>
    <List>
      <Holder>
        <Name>Peter</FolderName>
        <Age>35</Age>
      </Holder>
      <Holder>
        <Name>John</FolderName>
        <Age>25</Age>
      </Holder>
      <Holder>
        <Name>Micheal</FolderName>
        <Age>45</Age>
      </Holder>
      <Holder>
        <Name>Kenin</FolderName>
        <Age>28</Age>
      </Holder>
    </List>
  </Settings>
```

how to remove the "Kenin" holder completely 
below code is only remove the Name but i want to remove the kenin
holder completely

```
            Dim e = From element In _xdoc.Descendants("Name") Where element.Value = "Kenin" Select element
        e.Remove()
```

Comment: Select element.Parent ?

Comment: yes dats great i missed that one thanks Mino

Comment: posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select parent element which should be wrapping element for name:

```
Dim e = From element In _xdoc.Descendants("Name") Where element.Value = "Kenin" Select element.Parent
e.Remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
    'for testing
    Dim xe As XElement = <Settings>
                             <List>
                                 <Holder>
                                     <Name>Peter</Name>
                                     <Age>35</Age>
                                 </Holder>
                                 <Holder>
                                     <Name>John</Name>
                                     <Age>25</Age>
                                 </Holder>
                                 <Holder>
                                     <Name>Micheal</Name>
                                     <Age>45</Age>
                                 </Holder>
                                 <Holder>
                                     <Name>Kenin</Name>
                                     <Age>28</Age>
                                 </Holder>
                             </List>
                         </Settings>

    xe...<Name>.Where(Function(el) el.Value = "Kenin").Select(Function(el) el.Parent).Remove()
```